# How to use boost lambda to populate a vector of pointers with new objects

Tags: c++, stl, boost, lambda, containers

I've recently started using boost lambda and thought I'd try and use it in places where it will/should make things easier to read.

I have some code similar to the following

```
std::vector< X * > v;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; ++i )
    v.push_back( new X() );
```

and later on, to delete it...

```
std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), boost::lamda::delete_ptr() );
```

Which neatly tidies up.

However, I thought I'd have a go at "lambda-ising" the population of the vector using lambda... That's then the fireworks started...

I tried..

```
std::generate_n( v.begin(), 20, _1 = new X() );
```

but this threw all kinds of compiler errors.

Any ideas which is the best "lambda" way to achieve this.

Thx
Mark.

Comment: Generally, don't store dynamically allocated pointers in a vector - your code isn't exception safe and will leak memory if a constructor of X fails.

Comment: Hi Joe, I'd be interested on expanding on this. I'm not sure how X's constructor could fail and leak memory. I thought the C++ standard said that new, in the face of exceptions, would return null and clean up the memory before rethrowing the exception. Of course I could be completely wrong.

Comment: @ScaryAardvark. New throws std::bad_alloc if it's out of memory - it never returns null unless you use the non-throwing form.

Comment: As for the memory leaks, I'm slightly wrong - your code doesn't leak if 'new X()' throws, it leaks if v.push_back() throws.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that does what you want:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/construct.hpp>

typedef int X;

int main() {
  std::vector<X*> v;
  std::generate_n( std::back_inserter(v), 20, boost::lambda::new_ptr<X>() );
  std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), boost::lambda::delete_ptr() );
}
```

You might want to consider using boost::ptr_vector though, as using a std::vector with dynamically allocated pointers in an exception safe way isn't easy.

Comment: If you wanted to achieve that you could just stick a v.reserve(20) infront of the generate_n call.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider:

```
static const int PtrVectorSize = 20;

// ....
v.resize(PtrVectorSize);
generate_n(v.begin(), PtrVectorSize, new_ptr<X>());
```

Also, you could use [boost::ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) and save your self the deletes.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly more legible. I like the way you've got rid of the back_inserter by resizing..

Comment: It is most likely a little more efficient to do a reserve or a resize prior to filling the generate, and I normally favor the resize/iterator over the reserve/back_inserter for sequences of a known size, though I suppose the second one could be considered "safer" in an exceptional sense.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you with lambda, but have you looked at [boost::assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) library?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After an extra bit of playing I came up with this...

```
std::generate_n( std::back_insert_iterator< std::vector< X* > >( ip ), 20, new_ptr< X >() ) );
```

I'm not quite sure this is as elegant. From a programming perspective, it may be, but from a "in-6-months-time-will-I-know-what-this-was-meant-to-do" perspectice, I'm not sure...

Feel free to point out better ways of doing this.

Comment: At least std::back_inserter(v) makes it a little more readable.

Comment: std::back_inserter's template target is a type not an instance so unfortunately it has to be std::vector< X * >, not v

Comment: back_inserter is a function so it can automatically deduce the tempalte argument - see my answer below.

Comment: Ah. sorry, I missed the fact it was a function. Good thinking :o)